# Allow CORS in react-oidc-context/oidc-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect

I want to add OAuth to my react application using a custom OAuth authentication provider. I have tried to use [react-oidc-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-oidc-context) and [oidc-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-react), but with both libraries, I get blocked by CORS policy. I cannot figure out how I add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header since the libraries request the `openid-configuration`-file from the auth provider under the hood. I can pass `metadata` or `UserManager` to the `AuthProvider`, which, as the [docs](https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts/blob/937b2d6/src/OidcClientSettings.ts#L30) say, `"Provide metadata when authority server does not allow CORS on the metadata endpoint"`, but I cannot figure out how to use them/what value to pass since there is no example.

Is there a way that I can add the CORS-header or another way of making the OIDC-call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS is something that needs to be configured in the Authorization Server (AS) when your React client is registered. Almost all ASs support CORS these days. You cannot make it work from React code.

**LIBRARY SETTINGS**

My [code example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts) shows an SPA config, and an alternative to downloading metadata is to provide a `metadata` JSON object with [endpoint locations](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/index.d.ts#L524):

```
authorize_endpoint
end_session_endpoint
token_endpoint
jwks_endpoint
```

However, when the library calls the last two endpoints it will still need to make cross origin requests.

**BACK END PROXYING**

If the AS definitely does not support CORS then one option is to double hop calls to the last two endpoints via your own back end component. This should not be necessary with any up to date AS though.

Comment: The AS does not support CORS, but I have asked the team if they can add it. I will get back when there are news in the case.